# While running a flask app code, getting the following error

Tags: flask

## I have appended the code and the error here - my data is not loading and I see one error as no feature to analyse. I have created a folder structure like this screenshot[image] #

```
# Flask Packages
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap 
from flask_uploads import UploadSet,configure_uploads,IMAGES,DATA,ALL
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 

from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os
import datetime
import time


# EDA Packages
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# ML Packages
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC


# ML Packages For Vectorization of Text For Feature Extraction
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Configuration for File Uploads
files = UploadSet('files',ALL)
app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST'] = 'static/uploadsDB'
configure_uploads(app,files)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///static/uploadsDB/filestorage.db'

# Saving Data To Database Storage
class FileContents(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300))
    modeldata = db.Column(db.String(300))
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Route for our Processing and Details Page
@app.route('/dataupload',methods=['GET','POST'])
def dataupload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csv_data' in request.files:
        file = request.files['csv_data']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        # os.path.join is used so that paths work in every operating system
        # file.save(os.path.join("wherever","you","want",filename))
        file.save(os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename))
        fullfile = os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename)

        # For Time
        date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

        # Exploratory Data Analaysis function
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('static/uploadsDB',filename))
        df_size = df.size
        df_shape = df.shape
        df_columns = list(df.columns)
        df_targetname = df[df.columns[-1]].name
        df_featurenames = df_columns[0:-1] # select all columns till last column
        df_Xfeatures = df.iloc[:,0:-1] 
        df_Ylabels = df[df.columns[-1]] # Select the last column as target
        # same as above df_Ylabels = df.iloc[:,-1]


        # Model Building
        X = df_Xfeatures
        Y = df_Ylabels
        seed = 7
        # prepare models
        models = []
        models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
        models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
        models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
        models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
        models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
        models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
        # evaluate each model in turn


        results = []
        names = []
        allmodels = []
        scoring = 'accuracy'
        for name, model in models:
            kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
            cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
            results.append(cv_results)
            names.append(name)
            msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
            allmodels.append(msg)
            model_results = results
            model_names = names 

        # Saving Results of Uploaded Files  to MySql DB
        newfile = FileContents(name=file.filename,data=file.read(),modeldata=msg)
        db.session.add(newfile)
        db.session.commit()     

    return render_template('details.html',filename=filename,date=date,
        df_size=df_size,
        df_shape=df_shape,
        df_columns =df_columns,
        df_targetname =df_targetname,
        model_results = allmodels,
        model_names = names,
        fullfile = fullfile,
        dfplot = df
        )




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## so the above is the code, errors are as follows

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /dataupload [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/girish/Desktop/StartAutoML/App.py", line 101, in dataupload
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 342, in cross_val_score
    pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 206, in cross_validate
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 458, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1220, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 573, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 470, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1091, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2018 16:34:26] "POST /dataupload HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

## data load has to happen through the sqlalchemy and am using a filestorage.db and I do not see any data and the app is not running

Comment: Could you please edit your question to put the code in a code block, tell us what you are trying to do, what output you expect and what you have tried so far. Also including some of the code would help the community find out what's going on. Just looking at an unformatted  error code will turn many people away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting from

```
File "/Users/girish/Desktop/StartAutoML/App.py", line 101, in dataupload
cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
```

and the error is

`ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1091, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.`

Check [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)
 and try to find which argument is the reason for the ValueError, i.e. doesn't have the proper value for the function `model_selection.cross_val_score()`.

Hope you get some directions.